# discord.js v12 trying to play a voice in voicechannel it doesnt play but there is no error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
const tokens = [




];
const chnls = [
"1004439734736666754",
"1004439735822995457",
"1004439737056112691",
"1004439739266510878",
"1004439741573386310",



];
const x = [];
for (let index = 0; index < tokens.length; index++) {
const token = tokens[index];
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login(token);

let concon;
client.on('ready', async () => {
console.log(client.user.username)
await client.user.setActivity({
name: "❤ Psychopath",
type: "PLAYING"
});
concon = await client.channels.cache.get(chnls[index]).join()
});
let xx;
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (prev, cur) => {

if (cur.member.user.bot) return;
if (cur.channel && (cur.channel.id === chnls[index])) {
if (cur.channelID === prev.channelID) return;
if ((cur.member.roles.highest.rawPosition < cur.guild.roles.cache.get("1004439685315182722").rawPosition)) { //REGISTER ID
xx = await concon.play('./hosgeldin.mp3');
x.push(cur.member.user.id);
} else if (cur.member.roles.highest.rawPosition > cur.guild.roles.cache.get("1004439713240862871").rawPosition) {// KAYITSIZ ID
xx = await concon.play('./yetkili.mp3');
x.push(cur.member.user.id);
}
}
});
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (prev, cur) => {
if (cur.member.id === client.user.id) concon = await client.channels.cache.get(chnls[index]).join();
})
}
```

im trying to do a bot that when a admin comes to the room that plays yetkili.mp3 when a user comes hosgeldin.mp3 and i writed this but it doesnt work i dont get any errors or problem when i join to the voicechannel there is no errors and it doesnt plays the sound too i use djs v12 what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anything wrong with your code. I dont know what packages you have installed besides discord.js so i would suggest that you install `ffmpeg-static` (`npm i ffmpeg-static`). Please let me know if you already have ffmpeg installed.